# Parsing a list/dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to do some automation, but got stuck at this:

```
ipreparray =
[{'rep': 'B'}, {'rep': 'L'}, {'rep': 'M'}, {'rep': 'H', 'Ips': ['147.56.24.35'], 'ipC': '2'}]

[{'rep': 'B', 'Ips': ['142.56.24.50'], 'ipC': '2'}, {'rep': 'L'}, {'rep': 'M'}, {'rep': 'H'}]
```

How can I only extract only these key:value pairs?

```
{'rep': 'H', 'Ips': ['147.56.24.35'], 'ipC': '2'}

{'rep': 'B', 'Ips': ['142.56.24.50'], 'ipC': '2'}
```

i.e. if there are additional values along with 'rep' which are 'Ips' & 'IpC'

Adding code here:

```
def get_traffic_stats(service, domain_name, date):
   try:
       query = 'domains/%s/trafficStats/%s' %(domain_name,date)
       traffic_stats = service.domains().trafficStats().get(name=query).execute()
       json_str = json.dumps(traffic_stats)
       resp_dict = json.loads(json_str)
       a = domain_name
       b = ','
       domrep = str(resp_dict.get('domainReputation'))
       spamratio = str(resp_dict.get('userReportedSpamRatio'))
       spf = str(resp_dict.get('spfSuccessRatio'))
       dkim = str(resp_dict.get('dkimSuccessRatio'))
       dmarc = str(resp_dict.get('dmarcSuccessRatio'))
       encrypt = str(resp_dict.get('inboundEncryptionRatio'))
       #iprep = next((i for i, item in enumerate(resp_dict) if item['ipReputations'] == 'HIGH'), None)
       final = date + ',' + a + b + domrep + b + spamratio + b + spf + b + dkim + b + dmarc + b + encrypt #+ b + iprep
       domain = a + b + domrep
       for x, y in resp_dict.items():
           if (x== "ipReputations"):
               ipreparray = []
               ipreparray = y
               print(ipreparray)
               for dic in ipreparray:
                    for val in dic.values():
                        print(val)
               #for index in range(len(ipreparray)):
                    #for key in ipreparray[index]:
                        #print(ipreparray[index][key])
       #print (final)
       #print(keys)
       #print (domain)
       return str(final)

trafficStats = {'name': 'domains/account.net/trafficStats/20210718',
                'ipReputations': [{'rep': 'B'},
                                  {'rep': 'L'},
                                  {'rep': 'M'},
                                  {'rep': 'H', 'Ips': ['141.54.247.35-141.54.247.41', '141.54.247.44'], 'ipC': '8'}],
                'domainReputation': 'HIGH',
                'spfSuccessRatio': 1,
                'dkimSuccessRatio': 1,
                'dmarcSuccessRatio': 1,
                'inboundEncryptionRatio': 1,
                'deliveryErrors': [{'errorClass': 'TEMPORARY_ERROR', 'errorType': 'SUSPECTED_SPAM'}]}
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing it? if yes, can you please share the code.

Comment: @martineau Apologies, I have updated the question adding the code as well.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed:  I have updated the code. TrafficStats is storing the actual response from API, Inorder to parse it I am using the below code. .get() is unable to give me results due to nested list/dict in 'ipReputations'

Comment: `next((dct for dct in ipreparray if 'Ips' in dct and 'ipC' in dct), None)` ?

Comment: @Axe319: Thanks a lot! this is what exactly I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a clever one-liner like in @Axe319's comment, but is arguably more readable and might be a little easier to extend:

```
ipreparray1 = [{'rep': 'B'},
               {'rep': 'L'},
               {'rep': 'M'},
               {'rep': 'H', 'Ips': ['147.56.24.35'], 'ipC': '2'}]

ipreparray2 = [{'rep': 'B', 'Ips': ['142.56.24.50'], 'ipC': '2'},
               {'rep': 'L'},
               {'rep': 'M'},
               {'rep': 'H'}]

def extractor(ipreparray):
    for dct in ipreparray:
        if {'Ips', 'ipC'} <= dct.keys():
            return dct

print(extractor(ipreparray1))  # -> {'rep': 'H', 'Ips': ['147.56.24.35'], 'ipC': '2'}
print(extractor(ipreparray2))  # -> {'rep': 'B', 'Ips': ['142.56.24.50'], 'ipC': '2'}
```